# Heroku Github actions deployment - CI/CD - Push rejected, cannot delete main branch

Tags: heroku, yaml, devops, github-actions, cicd

I have a typescript application and I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline with github actions in order to build, test and deploy my app to heroku.
I used this actions https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku#deploy-custom-branch and all the steps of are executed successfully except for the deployment, where I obtain this error

[image]

I also tried to force master branch using "branch" option but nothings change. This is my YAML file

name: Deploy

on: [push]

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install
        run: npm i
        
      - name: test
        run: npm run test-git

      - name: build
        run: npm run build-full
                
      - uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 # This is the action
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: "appname" #Must be unique in Heroku
          heroku_email: "myemail"          
          appdir: "dist"
```

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/akhileshns/heroku-deploy#options? Please give a [mre] **as text**, but note in the YAML you've shown you're _not_ actually using the `branch` option.

Comment: Yes, As I wrote, I used that guide. Branch option is not showed beacuse as I wrote, nothing changed, so I revoved that option